# How to allow the user to input only one type of data on the command-line?

Tags: c#, command-line, user-input

I am writing a program in which one of its characteristics is: no error occurs because of data entry that are not the same type of variable that receives it. And so I would know how to allow the user to enter only one data type at the prompt. I already know how to use `try-catch`, but I would like to do not use it.

**Edit:**

The user must to input only **float type** values

**Please give me an example.**

Comment: Can you give an examples of the types of data a user may put in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since all command line parameters are strings, you can only parse them. If you expect a float value, you would do something like:

```
float f;
bool success = Float.TryParse(parameter, out f);
if(success)
{
    ....
}
else
{
    ....
}
```

If the TryParse was a success, the value is now assigned to f. Otherwise, f == 0.0.

Comment: I'll test your answer if it work, I accept it as the correct.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
string usrInput = Console.ReadLine();
while(!isValid(usrInput))
{
   Console.Write("Invalid Input. Enter a valid value");
   usrInput = Console.ReadLine();
}

//continue to use input here
```

Write your valid function

```
private void isValid(string input)
{
   //use regex
   //use something else
   //if test passed return true 
   //return false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way without needing a try-catch block would be to attempt to parse the input and make a control flow decision based on whether the input was successfully parsed. For example, you could continually ask for valid input while the user input is *not* successfully parsed:

```
float myValue;
do 
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter a valid value: ");
} while (!Float.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out myValue))

// myValue contains a valid float, do something with it now...
float percent = myValue / 100.0f;
```

All of .NET's number types include a `TryParse` method, so if you have other input types you can change the example accordingly (`Integer.TryParse()`, `Double.TryParse()`, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

The console only reads text. If you want to ensure the user only enters data of a given type, I suggest you create general methods e.g. GetDate() which use TryParse methods and loop until the user enters a string which can be parsed to that type.

You would have to work in your own command escape strategy so it feeds the escape all the way back up to the method which called GetDate() to let it know the user escaped.